# laravel 5 AdminLTE2 /auth/login not working

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

Hello i am new laravel and mongoDB, in my project i am trying to use laravel and mongoDB. I am successful to installed mongoDB as well as bootstrap thems AdminLTE2 this is link of AdminLTE2 https://github.com/acacha/adminlte-laravel. But now i am facing problem when user login. Following my code

Route.php

```
<?php
   Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome'); });
  Route::post('/auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
```

login.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ url('auth/login') }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email"/>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="checkbox icheck">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                </label>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
        </div><!-- /.col -->
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my AuthController.php

```
<?php
   namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
   use App\User;
   use Validator;
   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

 class AuthController extends Controller
 {

use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new authentication controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
}
```

after login form submit i getting this error

```
FatalErrorException in Builder.php line 1493: Call to a member function compileSelect() on a non-object
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel default auth controller based on Eloquent ORM. Laravel Eloquent doesn't have default support for MongoDB database. If you want to use MongoDB, you need to install [Laravel MongoDB package](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) and configure database driver. As a newbie, this not good idea to explore MongoDB in the beginning, instead try SQL database management system for better learning purpose.

```
<?php 

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent {

    //protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'users';

}


?>
```